# Is delete[] equal to per element delete. c++

Tags: c++, memory-management, delete-operator

Everyone!

Lets say I'm writing the Array class and want to optimize construction

```
data = reinterpret_cast<T*>(new char[sizeof (T) * size]);
    for ( int i = 0; i < size; ++i ) {
        new(&data[i]) T(some_value);
}
```

And now I'm wondering how to free memory correctly:

1. `delete[] data;`
2. `for ( int i = 0; i < size; ++i ) {
       data_[i].~T ();
   }`

Comment: Are you trying to rewrite [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)?

Comment: What happens if allocated array is not the right alignment for T?

Comment: @NathanOliver, of course I'm not trying to do this:-) That's all my curious imagination.

Comment: @NeilKrik, I can't image such situation. Could you please provide an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression **delete[] data** must match the **new T[]** that created the array on the heap, so that **T** is the type of ***data**. Otherwise the behavior of the program is undefined (5.3.5).

In your example, the type of **data** and ***data** is unknown. If **T** is not **char**, the behavior is undefined.

You should **not** call **delete[] data**, even after calling the destructors in the loop. It would be better to call **delete[] reinterpret_cast<char*>(data)** to avoid undefined behavior. The destructors of type **T** must be called before freeing the memory.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the destructors first before `delete`ing the data.

```
// First step
for ( int i = 0; i < size; ++i ) {
    data_[i].~T();
}

// Second step
delete [] data;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// First, you must call the destructors, so that objects will be destroyed
for ( int i = 0; i < size; ++i ) {
    data_[i].~T ();
}

// Then, deallocate memory from the heap.
delete[] data;
```